# Show Axes text vertically besides column in ng2-google-chart

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, ng2-google-chart

[image]

I am using ng2-google-charts - 4.0.0 version. I want to display hAxis text beside the column.
I tried using slantedText and slantedTextAngle but, it does not support inside the chart.
It would be good if anyone can help with it.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get the x-axis labels inside the chart is to use the following option.

```
theme: 'maximized'
```

however, this option will ignore the `slantedText` option.

another method would to hide the x-axis labels,
and use a line style annotation.
this will add a rotated label inside the bar.
we can make the actual annotation line transparent.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}, 'y'],
    ['Alarms', 'Alarms', 100],
    ['Admin State', 'Admin State', 100],
    ['Opr. State', 'Opr. State', 100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      style: 'line',
      stem: {
        color: 'transparent',
        length: 0
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: 'percent',
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

note: there are no options to align the annotation.
if we want the label off to the right,
you can try reducing the size of the bar, with the following option.

```
bar: {
  groupWidth: 20
},
```

or we can manually move the labels on the chart's ready event.
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}, 'y'],
    ['Alarms', 'Alarms', 100],
    ['Admin State', 'Admin State', 100],
    ['Opr. State', 'Opr. State', 100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      style: 'line',
      stem: {
        color: 'transparent',
        length: 0
      }
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: 20
    },
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: 'percent',
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      var labelBounds = label.getBBox();
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start');
        label.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(label.getAttribute('x')) - chartBounds.top - labelBounds.height);
        label.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(label.getAttribute('y')) + labelBounds.height);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

note: this will work in angular, just need to add the ready event, the angular way.